# If just one conditional is false then python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a question related to if statement. I have multiple conditions as below example:

```py
if a==a or b==b or c==c or d==d or e==e or f==f or g==g:
    print("the same")
```

But I would also like to see if one of the conditions may be false but no matter which. Example:

```py
cond = ['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True']
# print("the same")

cond = ['False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True']
# print("Not the same, but one is ok")

cond = ['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'True', 'True']
# print("Not the same, but one is ok")

cond = ['True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True']
# print("Not the same")
```

Comment: For multiple conditional statements, they should be in brackets - e.g. `if (a==a) or (b==b) or ...`

Comment: In terms of what you would like to see, what have you actually tried so far? What is your specific problem?

Comment: An object is always equal to itself before overloading `__eq__` or `__ne__` magic methods...

Comment: @EmiOB The equal comparison takes precedence over the or operation, so parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: if you re looking for a `False` in a list use `all(list_of_boolean)`

Comment: @to_data It's a list of strings not booleans. *bool('False') == True*

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if using strings to represent True/False is a great idea but in the context of the question then this will work:

```
def check_cond(cond):
    assert cond.count('True')+cond.count('False') == len(cond)
    assert 'True' in cond
    if cond.count('False') > 1:
        return 'Not the same'
    return 'the same' if len(set(cond)) == 1 else 'Not the same, but one is ok'

conditions = [['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True'],
              ['False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True'],
              ['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'True', 'True'],
              ['True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True']]

for cond in conditions:
    print(cond, check_cond(cond))
```

**Output:**

```
['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True'] the same
['False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True'] Not the same, but one is ok
['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'True', 'True'] Not the same, but one is ok
['True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True'] Not the same
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant to be able to display a custom message on any specific count, else a default message:

```
def check(cond):
    return {
        0: 'the same',
        1: 'Not the same, but one is ok'
    }.get(sum(x=='False' for x in cond),
          'Not the same'  # default message
         )
          
check(['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True'])
# 'the same'

check(['False', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True'])
# 'Not the same, but one is ok'

check(['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'True', 'True'])
# 'Not the same, but one is ok'

check(['True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'True', 'True'])
# 'Not the same'
```

##### with booleans

*NB. it would be much better to use booleans instead of strings!.*

```
def check(cond):
    return {
        0: 'the same',
        1: 'Not the same, but one is ok'
    }.get(len(cond)-sum(cond),
          'Not the same'
         )
          
check([True, True, True, True, True, True, True])
# 'the same'

check([False, True, True, True, True, True, True])
# 'Not the same, but one is ok'

check([True, True, True, True, False, True, True])
# 'Not the same, but one is ok'

check([True, True, True, False, False, True, True])
# 'Not the same'
```